# 2D char array recursive search for largest group

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array

Ok, so this is my assignment. I conceptually understand what needs to be done, but I am having trouble on how I should go about executing it.

> Write a program which accepts a filename (as a "command parameter") for a two dimensional grid of random letters and returns the name and the number of groups of A, groups of B, etc. (Attached is an example of a portion of a solution for 7.46 in the text, as written.)
>
> You may assume the grid is exactly 10 rows and 20 columns.
>   There can be up to 3 unique characters (not that the upper bound matters to the algorithm).
>   NOTE: You should not need to know how many unique characters actually exist before processing begins, but assuming an "upper bound" just gives your code the ability to "prepare" for a given amount.
>
> The grid does not "wrap" (ie. moving off the left side does not move you back onto the right, like Pac-Man)
>   If you find it easier to make the grid wrap around a torus (top connect to bottom / left connected to right), feel free to do so. Just indicate that you have made this design decision in you submission.
>   Wrapping the grid around a torus actually makes the recursive code a bit smaller, but it's just a bit more conceptually difficult.
>
> Groups are collections of matching letters connected either horizontally or vertically.
>   Diagonal elements are not connected.
>   Your program should display:
>
> The total number of unique groupings of each letter.
>   The letter (and corresponding size) of the largest group.
>   Examples:
>
> Input File :

```
BBBBBABAAAAABAABBBAA
AAAABBABBABBBABAABBA
AAABABABAABBBBBABBAB
BBAAAABAABBBBAABBBAB
BAAABAABAAABBBAAAABA
AABABBAAABBBABBBAABA
BABBAAAABABBBBBAAABB
BABABAABAAAABAABBBAA
BABBAAAABBBABBAAAABB
ABABBBBBABAAABABAAAA
```

> Largest group is A with 49 members starting at (0,7)
>   Group Counts: A = 17 groups, B = 22 Groups

```
BBBBBABXXXXXBAABBBAA
XXXXBBABBXBBBABAABBA
XXXBABABXXBBBBBABBAB
BBXXXXBXXBBBBAABBBAB
BXXXBXXBXXXBBBAAAABA
XXBABBXXXBBBABBBAABA
BXBBXXXXBABBBBBAAABB
BXBABXXBAAAABAABBBAA
BXBBXXXXBBBABBAAAABB
ABABBBBBABAAABABAAAA
```

> That's where the 49 are (I marked the A's as X's that make up the 49).

this is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    args = new String[]{"this is where the file path goes"};
    final File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    char[][] grid = new char[10][20];

    //Creates the 2d array
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        String c = input.nextLine();
        for( int col = 0; col < 20; col++){
            grid[row][col] = c.charAt(col);
        }
    }      

    display(grid);  
    search(grid);        
}

// method to display the input file. Assuming no grid is no more than 10 rows 
private static void display(char[][] grid){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
       for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++ ) {
           System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static void search(char[][] grid) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    checkRight();
    checkBelow();
}
```

I don't really know what to pass to my recursive algorithms or how to keep track of the unique characters. Here is the file I'm passing

```
CCCCACCBCCAACABBBBCA
AABCABCBABCBBBACBBCB
ABACACCAABCBCBBBCBAC
ABABCCCBAAACBBABBCCC
BABAAABCCAAACABACAAB
BBCCBCACBCBACABAACBB
BCCBCBCCCAABACCCCCBB
ABBBBCCBAACCABCBCBAB
BCAACCBCBACAACBABCCB
BCBAABCACAABABBBAABA
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How do you get 49 members with your input file at the example? can u highlight those?

Comment: @McKevin there you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package recursivesearch;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Recursion {

    public static ArrayList<Point> searched = new ArrayList<Point>();
    public static ArrayList<Point> groupOrigins = new ArrayList<Point>();
    public static int groups = 0;
    public static boolean finished = false;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    public static HashMap<Character, Integer> groupCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    public static char largestChar;
    public static int largestInt = 0;
    public static int largestIndex = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
        final Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
        char[][] grid = new char[10][20];

        // Creates the 2d array
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            String c = input.nextLine();
            for (int col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = c.charAt(col);
            }
        }
        numbers.add(0);
        display(grid);
        search(grid);
        // System.out.println("NUMBER SIZE"+numbers.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            // System.out.println("NUmber is "+numbers.get(i));
            if (numbers.get(i) > largestInt) {
                largestInt = numbers.get(i);
                largestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("INDEX IS "+ largestIndex);
        // System.out.println("Groups" + groups);
        // for(Point i :searched)
        // {
        // System.out.println("Searched" +i.toString());
        // }

        // System.out.println(map.toString());
        getLargest();
        /*
         * for(int i = 0;i<groupOrigins.size();i++) {
         * System.out.println("Group origin for group "+i +": "+
         * groupOrigins.get(i)); }
         */
        System.out.print("Largest Group is " + largestChar + " with "
                + largestInt + " members starting at ("
                + (int) groupOrigins.get(largestIndex).getX() + ","
                + (int) groupOrigins.get(largestIndex).getY() + ") "
                + "Group Counts:");
        java.util.Iterator<Entry<Character, Integer>> it = groupCount
                .entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Character, Integer> pairs = (Map.Entry<Character, Integer>) it
                    .next();
            System.out.print(pairs.getKey() + " = ");
            System.out.print(pairs.getValue());
            System.out.print(pairs.getValue() > 1 ? " Groups" : "Group");
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }

            it.remove();
        }
        input.close();
    }

    public static void getLargest() {
        largestInt = 0;
        java.util.Iterator<Entry<Character, Integer>> it = map.entrySet()
                .iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Character, Integer> pairs = (Map.Entry<Character, Integer>) it
                    .next();
            if (pairs.getValue() > largestInt) {
                largestChar = pairs.getKey();
                largestInt = pairs.getValue();
            }
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
        // System.out.println("Largest Char is " + largestChar);
        // System.out.println(largestInt);

    }

    // method to display the input file. Assuming no grid is no more than 10
    // rows
    private static void display(char[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void search(char[][] grid) {
        search(grid, 0, 0);

    }

    private static void search(char[][] grid, int x, int y) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                search(grid, i, j, grid[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void search(char[][] grid, int x, int y, char c) {

        search(grid, x, y, c, groups);
        if (finished == true) {
            // System.out.println("GROUP " + groups + " with Character " + c +
            // " has members of : " + numbers.get(groups));
            if (!map.containsKey(c)) {
                map.put(c, -1);
                groupCount.put(c, 1);
            } else {
                groupCount.put(c, groupCount.get(c) + 1);
            }
            if (map.get(c) < numbers.get(groups)) {
                // System.out.println("OVERWRITE");
                map.put(c, numbers.get(groups));
            }
            groups++;
            finished = false;
        }

    }

    private static void search(char[][] grid, int x, int y, char c, int group) {
        Point now = new Point(x, y);

        if (!searched.contains(now)) {
            // System.out.println(now.toString() + c);
            finished = true;
            searched.add(now);
            while (numbers.size() <= group) {

                numbers.add(0);
            }
            while (groupOrigins.size() <= group) {
                groupOrigins.add(new Point(-1, -1));
            }
            if (groupOrigins.get(group).equals(new Point(-1, -1))) {
                groupOrigins.set(group, now);
            }

            numbers.set(group, numbers.get(group) + 1);
            if (y - 1 >= 0) {
                if (grid[x][y - 1] == c) {
                    search(grid, x, y - 1, c, group);
                }
            }
            if (y + 1 < 20) {

                if (grid[x][y + 1] == c) {
                    search(grid, x, y + 1, c, group);
                }
            }
            if (x - 1 >= 0) {
                if (grid[x - 1][y] == c) {
                    search(grid, x - 1, y, c, group);
                }
            }
            if (x + 1 < 10) {
                if (grid[x + 1][y] == c) {
                    search(grid, x + 1, y, c, group);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: edited to match requirements.

Comment: that works terrifically. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: I hate to be a burden, but is there a way you could make it so the output only displays the Largest group and where that group starts, along with the number of groups for each character.

So it looks something like this: 

Largest group A is 49 members starting at (0,7).
Group Counts: A = 17 groups, B= 22 groups, C = 3 groups.

if not it's fine, I was just having a hard time modifying your code to do that.

@McKevin

Comment: @user2147096 Okay, I've now edited to match your requirements, dun forget to mark as answer ;).